# iOS7: UINavigationBar merges with status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I am new to `iOS` and the situation I am in in following

- I have a `UIViewController` that has `UITableView` and `UINavigationBar` as

> ```
> @interface CategoryGroupViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
> @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navigationBar;
> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
> @end
> ```

In `XIB` it looks like

[image]

When I run my application, it looks like

[image]

I looked around solutions online, and also tried setting

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

But this doesn't seem to resolve the issue. 
Can someone please guide as to what I am missing?

Thank you

Comment: if you want to use default navigationbar then on IB tap on view and set Topbar to "Opaque Navigation bar". so you will get 64 px navigatiobar default. but for that you have to use navigationcontroller in your window and add `self.navigationController.navigationbarhidden=NO` if you've hide. no need to take Navigatiobar in IB. if you want to use default bar.

Comment: It did not do anything useful. I still see it getting merged

Comment: Can you tell us what is your flow like "UIWindow > UINavigationController > UIViewController"

Comment: Assuming you have a strong reason for not wanting to use the default navigation bar that comes with being embedded in a nav controller? Then it's all about your constraints. I can post a solution if you want to roll your own bars?

Comment: have you managed to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to use default Navigationbar with NavigationContoller.

so your flow is UIWindow > UINavigationController > UIViewController.

in `appDidFinishlaunching`

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainscreen].bounds];
self.vc = [[CategoryGroupViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CategoryGroupViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.vc];
self.navC.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
self.window.rootViewController = self.navC;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Now run your application and you will get 64px navigationbar. if you want to title that viewcontroller then

in CategoryGroupViewController's viewDidLoad

```
self.title = @"Pick Group";
```

if you want to hide this navigationbar then simply use code in perticular controller. but once you hide then navigationbar will hide in whole app. so you have to manage it manually.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 7 and onwards , Apple has restricted use of Status bar and navigation bar. I mean it is transparent now.

There are still ways to achieve our goals.

**Way 1:** We can use a navigation bar image of 64 px (128 in @2x resolution).
It will automatically colorise our navigation bar and status bar as well.

**Way 2 :** We can opt another solution

```
 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

You need add the above in your `-(void)viewDidLoad` method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are explicitly intending to use your own navigation bars and not those provided by a UINavigationController, you need to add the top layout guide into consideration. Right now your bar is being constrained to the top of the view where instead it needs to take into consideration the height of the status bar. You also want to be able to respond to the status bar extending (like when you are in a call). These constraints would do the trick

```
id topGuide = self.topLayoutGuide;
UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationBar

//navBar.top == self.view.top
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[navBar]"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings (navBar)]];

//pin navBar to horizontal edges
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[navBar]|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings (navBar)]];

//navBar.bottom = statusBar.bottom + 44
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:navBar
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:topGuide
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1.f
                                                           constant:44]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. But resolved my problem by increasing `delta y position` of `view`.

[image]

Check out the above screen shot.you can add `delta y` position like this. This worked for me. Hope it would work for you. Try  this.